# I am not able to access my css & js files when i use rewrite url

Tags: php, css, url-rewriting

Before using rewrite url every this diplayed correctly

[image: without using rewrite url]

but when i used rewrite url

```
http://localhost/mgosoft/admin/userreg/
```

[image: when used rewite url]

please help me out with this thing thank you :)

Comment: You can use base tag to rewrite base without changing your relative paths, Documentation here-> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp u this comment if helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you are using php just use `$site_addr = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`
and append this before all your links like->

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $site_addr; ?>css/style.css">
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

@O-mkar nailed it pretty much. Another thing you can do - if you don't want to change all references through your whole project: rewrite them to the correct URL automatically using another htaccess line (for `/css/` directory)::

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*/css/([^/]+)$ /css/$1 [L, R=301]
```

Thís will rewrite any wrong url like `http://localhost/mode/movies/view/profile/css/style.css`

to the fixed resource path `http://localhost/css/style.css`

ofc. `localhost` needs to match the proper external hostname.

depending on how generic your original rewrite is, you should exclude resource paths from beeing rewritten again, or you end up with an infinite rewrite loop:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/javascript/ [NC]
```

etc...

---

As of your example given and the resource file is `assets/css/themes/simple/style.css`

You basically need to say: *Rewrite anything that ENDS with this String to the root folder*.
Thus, it would be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/css/themes/simple/ [NC] #skip, if already rewritten
RewriteRule ^.*/assets/css/themes/simple/([^/]+)$ /assets/css/themes/simple/$1 [L, R=301]
```

You can use this nice page to play around: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

put in the above example and the request url `http://localhost/mode/movies/assets/css/themes/simple/style.css` to see, it will become `http://localhost/assets/css/themes/simple/style.css`

ofc. you can play arround and redirect EVERY subfile of `/assets/` like that, then you dont need to create rules per file.

ps.: **If you are using `[L, R=301]` to redirect resources, the browser cache will work as well, cause it will remember the permanent move of the file requested.** - without R=301 it will think that's different files all the time.

Comment: @Omi this guy is right you can also use this method

Comment: @dognose my path is like this assets/css/themes/simple/style.css what should i change

Comment: @Omi added an example for that.

Comment: @dognose there is not only one css under assets there are many

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this
For your local version add

```
<base href="//localhost/mywebsite" />
```

to the head section

and for your live versions change it to

```
<base href="//your.domain.here" />
```

reference at http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4